# Access 2013 with Azure SQL - Dynamic IP

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, azure

I have created a simple Access 2013 database that is linked via ODBC to an Azure SQL server. Due to the limitations of Azure SQL (must declare IP addresses) and the security risks involved of opening the IP range to encompass all IP's, what is the simplest way to have the Access database talk to the Azure SQL server with unknown IP addresses without opening up all the IP's? I would like to keep this all in Azure if possible.

Is there a way to create a simple web layer in which the Access database will speak to, thus I only need to open the IP address for the web layer? If so, will I need to change how the Access database functions? There are some SQL functions that change the database directly when users change/add information...

I have done a little research and it appears I must host my own web layer, but how could I set it up in Azure to work with the existing Access database?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of, is to have some kind of registration procedure for the potential user.

When approved, log the calling IP address and run a script that adds this IP address to the pool of allowed IP adresses of your Azure database. This, I believe, can be done via an API call or a PowerShell script, though I have no idea of the details.